# DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()`

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this warning when using findOneAndUpdate() of mongoose.

> DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated.

Yeah I know if i put **usedFindAndModify** to **false**, this will remove the warning but my question is if there is a better option to do this? and at what extent deprecation warnings are to be taken seriously?